# Why is Mathematica changing the output display format?

Tags: functions, output-formatting, formatting, latex

I do a command like

```
  Table[i^5/(i^5 + 7*i + 1) Sin[x]/E^(3 i x), {i, 1, 5}]
```

The output shows up as

$$\left\{\frac{1}{9} e^{-3 x} \sin (x),\frac{32}{47} e^{-6 x} \sin (x),\frac{243}{265} e^{-9 x} \sin (x),\frac{1024 e^{-12 x} \sin (x)}{1053},\frac{3125 e^{-15 x} \sin (x)}{3161}\right\}$$

Compare the last two entries to the first three. The issue is that the last two entries are a fraction, while the first 3 have a rational times an expression. This is also true when I copy as $\LaTeX$.

Why is *Mathematica* changing the way it is displaying the output, which is quite annoying as I am manually having to make the last two match the first three? Is there any way to have it produce a consistent output?

I have noticed this on both 12.3 and 13.0 on a Windows 10, x86 machine.

Comment: Please evaluate `$Post` and read about it in the docs, if applicable.

Comment: Is the issue that the last two entries are a fraction, while the first 3 have a rational times an expression? And what does manually matching mean?

Comment: @Syed: I just checked and I am not seeing anything there to control this particular case, but maybe it is not documented.

Comment: @CarlWoll: Correct. I go in manually and make them all consistent, that is, show a rational times an expression. Sometimes these are very long expressions and I want them to all look the same for my notes.

Comment: If `t` is your Table, then `FullForm /@ t` suggests that these entries  are identical. I can see the same thing in v12.2.0 on Win7-x64.

Comment: `t /. Times[r_Rational, p_Power, s_Sin] :> HoldForm[HoldForm[r]*p*s]` or `t /. Times[r_Rational, rem__] :> HoldForm[HoldForm[r]*rem]`

Comment: @BobHanlon: Is there any way to make this consistent regardless of the functions?

Comment: Try the second form in my comment

Comment: See https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/198744/4999 or https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/167118/4999

Comment: Is there some reason why it is formatting like this in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

Another workaround (This is meant just for fun's sake). By breaking the input into 2 Latex parts

```
toX[s_] := ToString@TeXForm@s;
data = Table[toX[i^5/(i^5 + 7 *i + 1)] <> toX[Sin[x]/E^(3 i x)], {i, 1, 5}]
```

[image]

Movie

[image]

To obtain back the Mathematica expression

```
 ToExpression[data, TeXForm]
```

[image]

Or can use MaTeX

```
 << MaTeX`
 MaTeX[data, Magnification -> 2]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You asked

> Is there any way to have it produce a consistent output?

and a truthful answer is uncertain because the way that Mathematica
produces output is mostly undocumented and subject to change. With
that understood, there are several ways that would tend to produce
output that is more consistent depending on how much effort you are
willing to expend. In effect, you can construct your own output
function that does exactly what you want, but that would duplicate
the work that is done by the default output function.

What I suggest here is one simple way that may do what you
want in this or similar situations, but it is only cosmetic and the
underlying result is different than what it looks. That is, you can
not use it for further manipulation unless you remove the wrapper.

Define the function

```
xx[x_] := Interpretation[x,x]
```

Apply it to your code as follows

```
Table[xx[i^5/(i^5 + 7*i + 1)] xx[Sin[x] E^(3 i x)], {i, 1, 5}]
```

The resulting output is what you would expect but the contents of the
second use of `xx[]` appears inside a pair of parenthesis. This may be
enough for your present situation without using more advanced methods.